# Flask Issue : Parameters not received at backend python script

Tags: python-3.x, flask, parameter-passing

I am facing a problem with flask.

I have a back-end python script which accepts 4 parameters. One of the parameters is 'file variable' (i.e a physical file located on drive ), while the other 3 are 'string variables'.

However, when I call the flask launch script ( which in turn calls my back-end python code), I receive only file variable, while the string variables are not received.

Below is the dummy python code :

```
@app.route('/route', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def func2():
    print("Posted file: {}".format(request.files['file']))
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    # var1 = str(data['var1'])
    # var2 = str(data['var2'])
    # var3 = str(data['var3'])
    var1 = request.files['var1']
    var2 = request.files['var2']
    var3 = request.files['var3']
```

I have tried the commented lines as well. But all I received at the backend is only file variabale, not the latter 3 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `string` variables are not files so they wont be in `request.files`. Try the following:

```
var1 = request.values['var1']
```